# How to create a table with columns named after values in other table

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a table, call it that has the column `attr_name`. How do I create a new table using the values from each row in `attr_name`? I think I'm close

```
conn=psycopg2.connnect("dbname='{}' user='{}' password='{}' host='{}'".format(db, username, password, host))


cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT attr_name FROM {}.{};".format(schema, tableName))

for row in cur:
    print(row)#this works as expected

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE {}.proj_attr ({}, {},…,{});".format(newTableName))
```

I need to fill in the `({}, {},...,{})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create columns:

```
columns = ["id serial primary key", "name text"]
```

You can use:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE {}.proj_attr ({})".format(newTableName, ", ".join(columns))
```

You don't mention what types the columns are, but you can use:

```
 columns = ["%s text" %(row[0], ) for row in cur.fetchall()]
```

If you want to make them all text.